# Jmeter multiple file upload from folder

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

I've managed to do a setup where Jmeter is looking into a folder with a Loop Controller, but the HTTP request is picking the same file from a folder with multiple files. How do I modify the below Test Plan for it to randomly select files from a folder and uploaded them to a web app?

My Test plan contains the following:

1. jp@gc - Directory Listing Data Source
2. Simple controller with file initializer with the following code in the BeanShell Sampler:
   String fileFolder = vars.get("FILE_FOLDER");

```
java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(fileFolder);

String[] files = folder.list();
int fileNum = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= files.length; i++){
//log.info("fileName: " + files[i-1]);

     if (files[i-1].equals(".DS_Store") == false && 
              files[i-1].equals(".svn") == false ) {

         vars.put("FILE_" + fileNum++, files[i-1]);
    }
}
vars.put("maxFileCount", files.length+"");
```

3. Loop controller with:

- Counter - ${maxFileCount} as Maximum value and FILENUM as Exported Variable Name
- BeanShell PreProcessor with the following code:

```
String index = vars.get("FILENUM");
log.info("file" + index);

String testFile = vars.get("FILE_" + index);
vars.put("UPLOAD_FILE", testFile);
log.info("uploaded file: " + testFile)
```

- HTTP Request where I defined as file path the destination variable name from the Directory Listing Data Source. I'm pretty sure Parameter Name and MIME type are correct, since the upload of a file works correctly.

Are the jp@gc - Directory Listing Data Source and the file initializer with the BeanShell Sampler from step 2 do the same thing? Is there another controller that I need to use for the http request to randomly pick files from the folder and not the same file each time?

I'm using Jmeter 5.5

I've seen the solution with reference to random file location as ${CURRENT_FILE} where required, but I couldn't manage to implement it. I'm a beginner with Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need Directory Listing Data Source at all as you're getting the files list via Beanshell
2. You need to use `${UPLOAD_FILE}` variable in the HTTP Request sampler
3. It will be more convenient to use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), in that case you won't have to worry about counting the loops and calculating the next file name
4. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as Groovy performance is much better, for your current scenario Beanshell is okay, but if you will be using scripting for conducting the load or heavy calculations it's better to consider migrating. More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I tried also without the simple controller, I tried modifying the File Path. Is there any other approach? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately your "didn't work" statement doesn't tell anything to me, check that your `${UPLOAD_FILE}` variable has anticipated value using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and see the request payload using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or better use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to compare requests from JMeter and from the real browser. Amend your JMeter to send the same request as browser and it will "work"

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dmitri. I managed to get my test plan to upload the files from a folder, but now I'm running into other issue. It only uploads them if the path is the same folder where my test plan is saved. I want my path to not depend on the test plan location. I checked the jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix in the jmeter.properties, but it is commented. I tried to write the path with different formats such as C:\folder1\folder2 or /folder1\folder2 or C:/folder1/folder2, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Moreover, it seems that in the request the file is detected, but the response says java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\folder1\Jmeter\file1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified). It looks into the folder where my test plan is.

Comment: You should not be using comments section for asking a different question. Instead of listing file names you can list files and get their absolute paths

Comment: @DmitriT : I need a clarification for the same question where i am using Directory Listing Data Source. I have set the destination variable name as `files` in Directory Listing Data Source but when i iterate over the loop controller (with loop count as fileCount) by passing the variable `files` in my HTTP request, it picks same file rather than pick different files that are available. Thanks in advance for your help !  Please refer this image for a snapshot https://file.io/gfIDZo6bbtm9